# I'm unable to access content-length of response headers in app.use() middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to access `content-length` of response headers in `app.use()` middleware:

```
const app = express();
app.use((req, res, next) => {

    //how to get content-length of res
    console.log("content-length", res);  //not able to access content-length
    next(); 

})
```

Comment: response.headers.get('content-length')

Answer (score 0):

```
response.headers.get('content-length')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The `Content-Length` header is of course unknown until the response has been finished. You must therefore execute the code that accesses it in the [`finish`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/stream.html#event-finish) event of the response object:

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.on("finish", function() {
    console.log(res.get("content-length"));
  });
  next();
});
```